# Adding items to ArrayList using a for loop throws outofbounds exception

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, button, arraylist

I am trying to add a number of JButtons to a JButton array list, however running the code gives an OutOfBounds Exception.
Here is the code, excerpt from main method:

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

        for(int i = 1; i<=5; i+=1) {

            int j = i;
            JButton btn = new JButton();
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println(j);
                }

            });
            buttonList.add(i, btn);
            mainPanel.add(buttonList.get(i));
            System.out.println("Print "+i);
```

Why is there an outofbounds exception here? I thought ArrayLists were dynamic, and started with an initial capacity of 10 anyways.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-. Indices start at 0 in Java. And you shouldn't even use this add() method anyway. Just use the add() method taking just an object as argument.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate you directing me to a document I have already seen, I don't see why what you've shown me explains the problem.

Comment: It says: "Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())". What is the size of the list initially? 0. What is your first index? 1. Is 1 > 0? yes. So it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted capacity and size to be the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<5; i+=1)
```

Comment: No problem, I  had also done this type of mistake many times.